# Postgresql to_char add characters to date

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc

I want to select dates with this format:
2018-11-25T16:00:00Z

So i tried to do this:

```
select to_char(registration_date, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SSZ')
from ...
```

but its output is:

```
2018-11-01STH24:17:35Z
```

The char 'T' changes the date output instead of just print it in the middle. I tried to add space next to the char 'T' like this :

select to_char(registration_date, 'YYYY-MM-DDT HH24:MI:SSZ')

and it works, but i need the date without spaces.

How can I add the char 'T' to the middle of the date, and the output will be the same as the first example?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, that's a really interesting one. I could reproduce it:

```
SELECT to_char('2018-11-01 15:21:24'::timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SSZ')
```

gives

```
2018-11-01STH24:21:24Z  -- note the S
```

And

```
SELECT to_char('2018-11-04 15:21:24'::timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SSZ')
```

gives

```
2018-11-04THH24:21:24Z -- note that THH still seems to remain as in the format string
```

---

The problem here is the format value `TH`. This string is interpreted as the "ordinal number suffix". It adds the suffix "ST", "ND", "RD", and "TH" for "first", "second", "third", "fourth" and others. In your format string this is combined from your `T` and the format string `HH24`.

See:

```
SELECT to_char('2018-11-01 15:21:24'::timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DDTH')
```

gives

```
2018-11-01ST
```

and

```
SELECT to_char('2018-11-04 15:21:24'::timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DDTH')
```

gives

```
2018-11-04TH
```

So in reality your examples above can be explained. The `S` is in reality a `ST`, the `H24` is an uninterpreted rest of the `THH24` (where the `TH` is already taken for the ordinal suffix). Same with second example where the `TH` is converted in a `TH` again, so it seems to be ignored.

---

Your **solution** is putting the T into double quotes:

```
SELECT to_char('2018-11-01 15:21:24'::timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSZ')
```

which gives:

```
2018-11-01T15:21:24Z
```

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=488aef31d335c7bd55027191d9c59574)

[Postgres date formatting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-formatting.html)